# capture a live image from camera using python, uiautomator

Tags: android, python

My application requires to capture a picture from the Android Camera.

from you Automatorviewer, the click softbutton of the camera is not being indentified, it is only displaying the View and the relative layout.

Please can someone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I found the answer using  the below

```
rowcount = d(textStartsWith="XXX").count
print rowcount
```

This returns the exact number of rows starting with same letters/characters